How to show a piped input file's text and the Python file output in bash?
I have a Python file called process.py that takes in user input one line at a time with the input function as follows and prints out the first letter of the input.
first_letter = []

for i in range(3):
    word = input("> ")
    l = word[0].upper()
    first_letter.append(l)
    print(f"{i}:{l}")

print("".join(first_letter))

I have a text file called tmp_in.txt that is piped to the Python file to simulate user input.
apple
banana
cherry

Is there a way to show the input along with the output in the console or piped to a file? So that the output looks like this:
> apple
0: A
> banana
1: B
> cherry
2: C
ABC

Bash or using another Python wrapper file is fine, but the original Python file process.py cannot be changed. The input call in process.py may not also necessarily have a ">" as the prompt text (i.e. it could be "", "Type word here:", etc.)
I've tried using the bash command cat tmp_in.txt | tee /dev/tty | python process.py but this just shows the input file all at once first then the output like such:
apple
banana
cherry> 0:A
> 1:B
> 2:C
ABC


There's nothing that does this automatically. You could use os.isatty() to check if input is coming from a terminal or not. If not, it can print the response after reading the input.

You have your python script issuing prompts and reading it's input, then outputting results, but your script is also issuing a prompt. You aren't going to be able to insert the line read into the output stream in place after each individual prompt but before the response to that line of data using any sort of outside logic.
